# How to use while function by checking whether the result is an element from a list or not

Tags: python, list, while-loop

i have this code

```
import random

list = [1,2,3,4,5]
random_number = 0

while any(random_number == list):
     random_number = random.randint(1,10)
     print(random_number)
```

but when i tried to execute it, it showed this following error

TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable

i want to loop the function as long as the random number generated is an element of the list. Can you please help me to fix that code?

Comment: That's not how `any` works.  You want `while random_number in list:`, but to do that you'll have to set `random_number` to something that's in the list to begin with -- 0 is not in the list.'

Comment: i see, changed the fungction as follows

`import random`
`list = [1,2,3,4,5]`
`random_number = 1`
`while random_number in list:`
`random_number = random.randint(1,10)`
`print(random_number)`

and the function is working as intended

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here.

First, it's probably a bad idea to overwrite the built-in `list`. Using a different name, like `lst`, should help you avoid it.

Second, that's not how `any` works. `any` returns `True` if any element of the iterable passed to it is a truth-y. If you must use it, you'd want something like `any(x == random_number for x in lst)`, but in all honesty, you're probably better off just using the built-in `in` operator.

And lastly, the initial value for `random_number` is `0`, which isn't in the list, so the loop will never be entered. Instead, you should initialize it to some value in the list.

Put this all together, and you'll get something like:

```py
import random

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
random_number = lst[0]

while random_number in lst:
     random_number = random.randint(1, 10)
     print(random_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code here:

First, `list` is a Python keyword (it's the `list` type) so avoid using this name.

Then, in Python, to check if an element is in a list, you should use the `in` keyword.

Third, if you are checking that the number is in the list, then you initial number should be in the list, otherwise it just exits the loop before it even starts.

```py
import random

mylist = [1,2,3,4,5]
random_number = 1

while random_number in mylist:
    random_number = random.randint(1,10)
    print(random_number)
```